# Algorithm Validation and Alternative Approaches for FDR Control in Combined Datasets

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, p-value, false-discovery-rate

We are currently working on a project involving multiple datasets reanalyzed with the same pipeline, where all data points (patient feature) have been filtered at 1% False Discovery Rate (FDR). As part of our analysis, we aim to combine these data points lists while controlling the number of false positives resulting from the combination. To formalize our approach to FDR control, we have implemented the following algorithm:

1. Each dataset has been independently filtered at 1% FDR, generating a q-value for each data point.
2. The adjusted-FDR for the combined datasets is calculated as follows: adjusted-FDR = FDR / number of datasets combined.
3. To be retained in the final combined dataset, each data point's current q-value must be lower than the corresponding adjusted-FDR.

As an illustration, if we desire an overall FDR control of 1%, and we have 5 datasets, the adjusted FDR threshold would be 0.01 / 5 = 0.002 (0.2%). Consequently, all q-values for data points in the combined dataset should be lower than 0.002. While we believe this approach provides a reasonable approximation for FDR control in the absence of decoy data points, we are keen to ensure its validity and explore alternative methods. Therefore, I am seeking your expertise and feedback on the following points:

Validation of the Approach: Is the outlined algorithm for adjusting FDR in combined datasets valid? Are there any potential limitations or assumptions we should be aware of? Could you kindly suggest any references or research papers that discuss similar FDR control methods in the context of combined datasets? We would like to explore related literature to strengthen our analysis.

Any insights or recommendations you can provide would be greatly appreciated.